# Send a key value list object to retrofit

Tags: android, hashmap, retrofit

I want to send this

```
"question_id": 1,
"answer_id": { 
    "answerId1": "value1",
    "answerId2": "value2"
}
```

through retrofit in android

I sent this

```
"question_id": 1,
"answer_id": [ 
    1,
    2
    ]
```

like that

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(".....")
@Field("question_id") String questionId, @Field("answer_id[]") ArrayList<String> answerId)
```

how to do the same for the first request? btw HashMap<String,String> is not working

Comment: [FieldMap](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded-using-fieldmap) Should work in this case i think.

Comment: @ADM how do i  state the field name?

Comment: No sure but try with `getSomething(@Field("question_id") String questionId, @FieldMap HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> answer_id)`

Comment: @ADM didn't work, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public interface myService {    

    @POST("/api/mypath/test")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    void getPositionByZip(@Query("question_id") String question_id, @FieldMap Map<String, String> answer_id);
}

// Map params need set key and value pair  like      
// answer_id.put("answerId1","value1");
// answer_id.put("answerId2","value2");
```

Comment: I think `@FieldMap` does not accept a value thats the problem

Comment: @FieldMap value should not empty and null.

Comment: Not accepting means getting any exception or not hitting to the server?

Comment: @Mr_vmh it means that it's not possible syntax wise, code won't run because it's a syntax error if you write this `@FieldMap("answer_id")`

Comment: it's only allowed like this `@FieldMap Map<String, String> params;

Comment: yes it's written up in my example that am using FormUrlEncoded

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson Class and it converts to a string :

```
 List<Answer> answerlist= new ArrayList<>();
 Answer model = new Answer();
 answerlist.add(model);
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String finallocation = gson.toJson(answerlist);


@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("example.com/question")
Observable<Response> sendAnswer(
        @Field("question_id") String question_id,
        @Field("answer") String answer);
```